# Ho test fwo different local wip domain with panther?

Tags: symfony, testing

I want to start using web tests in Symfony. In the application, I use two different domains ([with `wip` tld](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/symfony_server.html#defining-the-local-domain)) and I want to test with Panther if they return the correct result. For local development, I use the Symfony server.

```
symfony server:start --daemon --dir=/home/*/projects/project symfony
proxy:start symfony 
proxy:domain:attach subdomain.domain-test --dir=/home/*/projects/project symfony 
proxy:domain:attach www.domain-test --dir=/home/*/projects/project
```

and I've this test:

```
class MainRoutingControllerTest extends PantherTestCase
{
    use PantherTestTrait;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->prepareDatabase();
    }

    public function testPresentationHomepage(): void
    {
        $options = [
            '--proxy-server=http://127.0.0.1:7080/proxy.pac'
        ];
        $client = static::createPantherClient(['webServerDir' => __DIR__.'/../../public', 'browser' => 'chrome', 'browserOptions' => $options]);

        $client->request('GET', $this->getPresentationWebUrl());

        $this->assertResponseIsSuccessful(message: 'Wrong http response on presentation homepage');
        $this->assertSelectorTextContains('h1', 'Hello customer', message: 'Can not find expected H1');
    }
}
```

and when I run the test, I get the following error:

```
1) App\Tests\Controller\MainRoutingControllerTest::testPresentationHomepage
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownErrorException: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
  (Session info: chrome=116.0.5845.179)
```

don't know, waht I'm doing wrong.

I've tried for example chage the phpunit configuration

```
<phpunit>
    <listeners>
        <listener class="Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\SymfonyTestsListener">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="serverNames">
                    <value>www.domain-test.wip</value>
                </argument>
                <argument name="mockedNamespaces">
                    <value>
                        \App\Controller,
                        \App\Repository,
                    </value>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </listener>
    </listeners>
</phpunit>
```

but then I've got this error:

```
Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\Legacy\SymfonyTestsListenerForV7::__construct(): Argument #1 ($mockedNamespaces) must be of type array, null given
```